# How do I change the port used by Remix.run's local development server?

Tags: javascript, remix.run

By default, Remix.run seems to use Port 3000 for local development when running:

```
❯ npm run dev

> dev
> concurrently "npm run dev:css" "remix dev"

[0]
[0] > dev:css
[0] > tailwindcss -o ./app/styles/tailwind.css --watch
[0]
[1] Watching Remix app in development mode...
[1]  Built in 161ms
[1] Remix App Server started at http://localhost:3000
```

How do you change the port it runs on?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of v1.1.3 (~Jan 2022), the local development port is [configured](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/c746c6f75fb8a74da92df91113df5af7bf87adea/packages/remix-serve/cli.ts#L7) with the `PORT` environment variable.

Example:

```
PORT=10000 npm run dev
```

Gives

```
> dev
> concurrently "npm run dev:css" "remix dev"

[0]
[0] > dev:css
[0] > tailwindcss -o ./app/styles/tailwind.css --watch
[0]
[1] Watching Remix app in development mode...
[1]  Built in 162ms
[1] Remix App Server started at http://localhost:10000
```

Comment: in remix.config.js, `module.exports` -->(add) `devServerPort: 3003`

Comment: @Rahimuddin Nope, that's for the dev websocket server, not the dev server itself.

Comment: Works in prod too.

Comment: For beginners, you can modify `scripts`on`package.json` file and add this port. For instance, change the `"dev": "remix dev"` to `"dev": "PORT=10000 remix dev"`

Comment: as per this article https://ishu.dev/post/set-port-to-remix-application
for Dev environment you can use ".env" file but for prod you need to pass PORT=xxxx flag but it doesn work on windows, you need to use cross-env

Answer (score 1):

this may help, as per remix they automatially detect PORT from .env file, so just add

```
.env
PORt=any_number
```

reference :

```
 let port = await getPort({ 
   port: process.env.PORT ? Number(process.env.PORT) : 3000, 
 });
```